# Can't initialize struct with nested pointers to other structs

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, nested

I'm using a third party library which defines this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short nbDetectors;
    //! structure of detector status
    struct DetectorStatus
    {
        unsigned int lastError;         //< last detector internal error
        float temperature;              //< detector temperature
        detector_state state;           //< detector state
        unsigned short mode;            //< detector mode

        struct EnergyStatus
        {
            power_source powerSource;           //< front-end power source
            frontend_position frontendPosition; //< front-end position relative to the docking station

            struct BatteryStatus
            {
                bool present;                   //< battery present or not in the detector
                unsigned short charge;          //< charge level of the battery (in %)
                float voltageLevel;             //< battery voltage level
                float temperature;              //< temperature of the battery
                unsigned short chargeCycles;    //< number of charge/discharge cycles
                unsigned short accuracy;        //< Expected accuracy for charge level (in %)
                bool needCalibration;

            } batteryStatus;

        } * energyStatus;

        struct GridStatus
        {
            detector_grid grid;

        } * gridStatus;

    } * detectorStatus;

} HardwareStatus;
```

This struct is used by the library as data passed by one of its callbacks. So it's the library which fills it up, I just read it. So far, so good.

But now I'm writing an emulator for the device handled by this library, so now I have to fill up one of these structs and I can't get it right.

I tried this:

```
HardwareStatus status;
status.detectorStatus->temperature = 20 + rand() % 10;
e.data = &status;
m_pContext->EventCallback( EVT_HARDWARE_STATUS, &e );
```

When I compiled, I got:

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'status' used
```

Then I realized... The pointers inside the struct are pointing to garbage, nice catch Visual Studio! So then I tried to start by declaring an instance of the innermost struct (`BatteryStatus`), but that wouldn't compile... because it's not typedef'd (it says the `BatteryStatus` type is not defined)? So I got stumped... How do I fill the struct up?

Comment: Also, to set batteryStatus, you'd have to write `EnergyStatus::BatteryStatus s; status.batteryStatus = s;`  Note the qualifying `EnergyStatus::...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to have everything on the stack this should do it:

```
// Getting structs on the stack initialized to zero
HardwareStatus status = { 0 };
HardwareStatus::DetectorStatus detectorStatus = { 0 };
HardwareStatus::DetectorStatus::EnergyStatus energyStatus = { 0 };
HardwareStatus::DetectorStatus::GridStatus gridStatus = { 0 };

// "Linking" structs
detectorStatus.energyStatus = &energyStatus;
detectorStatus.gridStatus = &gridStatus;
status.detectorStatus = &detectorStatus;

// Now you can fill and use them
status.detectorStatus->temperature = 20 + 3 % 10;
//...
```

Comment: This works, but without the zeros in the struct initialization (I still can't edit other people's posts). Thanks!

Comment: Please note that this solution may be very dangerous if you plan to use the 'status' variable "crafted" this way outside the scope where these definitions are done. This is because it points internally to the data allocated on the stack and that stack will go away.

I would suggest you to allocate the memory dynamically.

Comment: @Lev: That's very true and it's not a problem, the struct is passed to a callback, and once it's done with it, it's no longer necessary

Comment: @dario_ramos: if this is your use case then everything is good :) Just be sure not to do any asynchronous stuff with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could value-iniitialize it:

```
HardwareStatus status = {};
```

If you want to instantiate a `BatteryStatus`, you can do that by fully qualifying the name:

```
HardwareStatus::DetectorStatus::EnergyStatus::BatteryStatus bs;
```

Comment: That's a good start, more elegant than memset'ting to 0, but... I still can't touch `detectorStatus->temperature` because `detectorStatus` is an invalid pointer

Comment: `HardwareStatus status = {};
    status.detectorStatus->temperature = 20 + rand() % 10;`

This compiled for me, apart from a warning about int to float conversion.

Comment: @Gnawme:  Your code assigns through a null pointer.  Why would you expect this to work?  Just because it builds doesn't mean its right.

Comment: @dario:  You haven't yet instantiated a `DetectorStatus` for `detectorStatus` to point to!

Comment: @JohnDibling: I was concurring with your value-initialization; I should have read the OP's question more closely...

Answer (score 1):

did you try memset'ing the struct to 0 ?

Comment: `memset(&status, 0, sizeof(status));`

Comment: Well, that solves the warning, but now all the struct's pointer are pointing to NULL (0 here)... So I still can't set `detectorStatus->temperature` (which is actually the only thing I want to do)